# Any attempts to install Gazebo in Cygwin lately?

Tags: gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I know this may be crazy talk, but has anyone tried to install Gazebo in Cygwin lately?
Although I see stale references to installing ROS on Cygwin, I think a couple of people have had some recent success with Groovy.. I also see that people have installed OGRE.
This makes be curious about Gazebo..

What would be the suspected/expected sticking points aka "opportunities for failure"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4286/any-attempts-to-install-gazebo-in-cygwin-lately?/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 319 on 2013-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've been helping to get experimental support for OSX as of gazebo 1.9.1; the biggest sticking point that required a major change to the gazebo code base involved supporting [Case Insensitive Filesystems](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/775/installation-fails-on-case-insensitive), which is now solved and should benefit a Windows port as well.

Dependency resolution is always tricky; we were fortunate to use the [homebrew formulae developed by the ROS team](https://github.com/ros/homebrew-hydro) for that, although I've heard that OGRE support on Windows is good. Take a peek at the [gazebo formula](https://github.com/osrf/homebrew-simulation/blob/master/gazebo.rb) for a brief list of some dependencies, though there are more that are unlisted because they are included with osx.

I haven't used Cygwin in quite a while, but I wish you luck. Please feel free to share your experience here or on the [gazebo issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues?status=new&status=open).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0